# hosting WPF inside Windows Form giving issues - C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winforms

I've created a .DLL in WPF. To use it in existing Windows Forms application I use `ElementHost`.

```
ElementHost eleHOst = new ElementHost();
UserWarps userWarps = new UserWarps();
eleHOst.Child = userWarps;
eleHOst.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

`UserWarps` is in WPF `.DLL` which has been add-referenced. Now the file does lot of 3D manipulations. I'm also using `Petzold.Media3D` for `3D lines` for wireframe modelling. Everything's working fine except that `WireLines` of `Petzold.Media3D` is not drawing any lines. If I reference the DLL from other `WPF` applications everything's fine, but hosting the UserControl of `wpf` in windows forms eliminates the lines/wireframes. Rest everything is perfect - `MeshGeometry3D`, Models, Visuals, functionalities etc.

Please suggest the way forward. could any alternative to `ElementHost` work? If it does then what is it?

Comment: is Modal or Non Modal Window ?

Comment: Move the "Edit/Solution" to an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adding answer originally added by OP in question as I don't want this question to
>   be closed just because of that.

Petzold has mentioned [here](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/08/310158.html) that hosting wpf in Windows forms causes the Wire frames to disappear. He also posts a work around which is very simple and worked perfectly:

> NOTE: For reasons discussed in paragraph 5, these Wire classes will
>   not work when
>        you're hosting 3D in Windows Forms, or when you're trying to print a 3D scene. To make it work, try replacing the static
>   `OnRendering` method in WireBase with the following:
>
> ```
> static void OnRendering(object sender, EventArgs args)
> {
>     foreach (WireBaseAndUltimateParent wirebaseAndParent in listWireBases)
>     {
>         WireBase wirebase = wirebaseAndParent.wirebase;
>         wirebase.OnRendering();
>     }
> }
> ```